# How many PathItem's in a PathItems Collection

Tags: photoshop-script

It seems that a PathItems collection cannot hold more than 998 PathItem's.

I am using:

```
var myPathItem = docRef.pathItems.add(NewPixel, lineSubPathArray);
```

where variable NewPixel varies from 1 to 999. But when it gets to 999 I get a notification saying that Photoshop might not support the function, while it has already done 998 iterations.

It says at the bottom of the ExtendScript Toolkit:
"General Photoshop error occurred. This functionality may not be available in this version of Photoshop".

What am I missing. Thank you. Stefania

Comment: I think a real question is why do you need more than 999 paths in one file? Are you sure this approach is correct?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your interest.
Problem solved. What I did was close the document (not the script), reopen it and repeat with different offsets applied to the iterations counter. Not a very elegant solution but it worked consistently, and I must be pragmatic. Breaks my heart from the point of view of clean coding but it worked.

Thank you,